# How to edit (Put) and delete items with WPF client

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, asp.net-web-api

I am using WebAPi services and WPF as a client.

Adding items and geting them back works fine, but I can't figure out, which is the right syntax to edit or to delete the selected items.

XAML code

```
<DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns = "False" ItemsSource="{Binding Authors}" CanUserDeleteRows="True" 
           Name="lboxBooks" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Margin="38,86,0,0"
           VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" SelectionChanged="lboxBooks_SelectionChanged"
           SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow">

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding AuthorId, Mode=TwoWay}"  x:Name="authorId">
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="firstname" Binding="{Binding Firstname, Mode=TwoWay}"  x:Name="firstnamecolumn">
        </DataGridTextColumn> 
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="lastname" Binding="{Binding Lastname, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="true" x:Name="lastnamecolumn">
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="title" Binding="{Binding BookTitle, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="true" x:Name="booktitlecolumn">
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Out" Binding="{Binding IsOut, Mode=TwoWay}"  x:Name="outcolumn" IsReadOnly="False" >
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Margin="1,1,1,1" Content="Delete" Name="btnDelete"  Click="Delete"/>

                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Code behind:

```
public async Task<T> updateData<T>(string path, T obj)
{
    HttpResponseMessage resp = this._client.PutAsJsonAsync(path, obj).Result;
    return await resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
}

public async void updateData (Author author)
{
    var result = await this._authorService.updateAuthor(author);

}

public void btnClickEdit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    var selected = lboxBooks.SelectedItem;

    _vm.updateData(selected); ?????????????
```

So this is the part where I am stuck, because I get an error:

> Error  1   The best overloaded method match for 'LibraryClient.ViewModels.MainWindowVM.updateData(LibraryClient.Models.Author)' has some invalid arguments

And the same thing goes for deleting. Can't seem to get the syntax right, so the selected row actually deletes from DB, not only removes from WPF view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast selected-item to your Bindable type in   `var selected = lboxBooks.SelectedItem;`

Eg;

```
Author a1 = (Author) lboxBooks.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: Thanks. Got rid of the error, but the update doesnt work nevertheless. It doesnt save the changes

Comment: @trii that must be some code level issue. if my answer solves your question, mark it as answer.